# How to find the Bytecode of Ethereum Smart Contract by just it's address

Tags: ether, web3.py, python, brownie

Hi actually I found the answer & I just wanted to share this with the community

You can use the `web3.py` or `brownie` module of Python to achieve this

- `web3.py`

```py
from web3 import Web3

# Connect to custom RPC network
rpc_url = 'http://localhost:8545'  # Replace with your custom RPC URL
#chain_id = 1337  # Replace with your custom chain ID
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(rpc_url))

# Replace with the address of your deployed contract
contract_address = "0x876807312079af775c49c916856A2D65f904e612"
# Get teh byte code  
contract_bytecode = web3.eth.getCode(contract_address).hex()
print(f"Contract Bytecode: {contract_bytecode}")
```

- `brownie`

```py
from brownie import web3

contract_address = "0x876807312079af775c49c916856A2D65f904e612"
contract_bytecode = web3.eth.getCode(contract_address).hex()
print(f"Contract Bytecode: {contract_bytecode}")
```

- Both will give the same result.

[image]

Comment: Gist URL https://gist.github.com/Aviksaikat/009de442900f90a5a7d5a2ab594a5986

Comment: for bownie make sure you have added the network in the brownie networks

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question

Comment: @SaikatKarmakar It is okey to answer to your own question. Please, do this